# Tensorflow pairwise dot product for batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras

I want to train a neural network that takes an input three list of floats for each element of the batch. For example an element of the batch will look like `vec = [vec_a, vec_b, vec_c] = [1, 2.,3.], [1.5, 6.7, 9.], [3.4, 0.4, 0.3]` and I would like the first layer of the network to return the pairwise dot product of each distinct element. In this case that would be `vec_a*vec_b+vec_a*vec_c+vec_b*vec_c` (`*` means dot product between two vectors in this case)

If I want to translate this into a tensorflow model I can do the following

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pairwise_dot_product(x):
  matrix_dot_product = tf.tensordot(x, tf.transpose(x), axes=1)
  matrix_sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(matrix_dot_product)
  matrix_diag_sum = tf.linalg.trace(matrix_dot_product)
  return (matrix_sum - matrix_diag_sum)/2

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(pairwise_dot_product, input_shape=(None, ), name="pairwise_dot_product"))
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
```

If I evaluate the first layer of the network on `vec`

```
model.layers[0].apply(vec)
```

I do get the correct answer (`57.480003`). Now the problem is that I would like to train this model for something that looks like this `training_data = [vec_1, vec_2, vec_3, ...]`. For the sake of simplicity let's say that  I have `training_data = [vec, vec, ...]`, so I expect the first layer of the network to return `[57.480003, 57.480003, ...]`. How can I modify the network to do that? I think the problem is that the `pairwise_dot_product` function I defined is applied to the entire training batch, but I would like to only be applied to each element of the batch (`vec`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way

```
def pairwise_dot_product(x):

    matrix_dot_product = tf.keras.backend.batch_dot(x, tf.transpose(x, [0,2,1]), axes=[2,1])
    matrix_sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(matrix_dot_product, axis=[1,2])
    matrix_diag_sum = tf.linalg.trace(matrix_dot_product)
    return (matrix_sum - matrix_diag_sum)/2

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(pairwise_dot_product, input_shape=(None,None), 
                                 name="pairwise_dot_product"))

vec = [[[1, 2.,3.], [1.5, 6.7, 9.], [3.4, 0.4, 0.3]]]
vec = tf.constant(vec*10) # repeat 10 times vec

model(vec)
```

results:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003,
       57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003, 57.480003], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: thanks for this! Can you explain how you came about picking those axes? What happens if I would like to train with vectors of N elements instead of 3?

Comment: transpose need to be adapted for 3D input (batch, 3,3) so we need to swap only the latest 2 axis. batch_dot are computed on the axis of interest. I don't see any problem with vectors of size 3x3, 10x10 or NxN